# 404 error on js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a small express/webpack app that I am writing to learn webpack and I have my files bundling up correctly however when I go to the browser and open up the URL it gives a 404 on my bundle.js file.

Here is my file tree: 
[image]

Here is the index.ejs file which is my page Im playing with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Webpack Intro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">
    <script src="bundle.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Good Stocks</h1>
<h2>Stocks</h2>
    <ul>
<% stocks.forEach(function(stock){ %>
     <li><%= stock.name %></li>
<% }); %>
    </ul>
<form action="/addStock" id="form" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="addStock" id="name"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="jsonButton">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Webpack in case it matters:

```
module.exports ={
    //This file tells you what files to include in webpack. You can list all your files in this file
    entry: [
        './src/assets/entry.js'
        ],
    //This file is what will go in the html file
    output:{
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
```

Finally browser error when I reload the page. 
[image]

I have tried placing the bundle.js file in different places, I have tried ./ ../ .../ .// or anything else I can think of to get the path correct. I put it in the src folder and went with ./src/bundle.js I am slightly confused on whether the path should be in relation to my app.js or my index.ejs file. App.js is the express app and index.ejs is my view for the home page. Oh also I am on a cloud9 instance.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What about `/bundle.js`?

Comment: didnt work, says 404. You can go to that URL right now and see.

Comment: Where is your express app serving static files from? From what I can tell, your express app is having no problem serving `styles/styles.css`. I would try adding a `scripts` directory, and putting `bundle.js` inside that, then referring to `scripts/bundle.js` in your view.

Comment: @carebdayrvis This appears to be the answer!

I had this but apparently / doesnt work for root? 
app.use(express.static("src/assets"));
app.use(express.static("src/styles"));
app.use(express.static("/"));